# How do I NOT remove trailing zeroes from a number in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How do I NOT remove trailing zeroes from a number in typescript?

For example, fees: number = 10.20; //this displays 10.2 on UI but I want to display 10.20

I have tried .toFixed() and .toPrecision() but it quite didn't work.

Comment: `10.2` and `10.20` are the same value, and are represented in memory by the exact same arrangement bits. The number itself has no idea the quantity of digits you want to display it to. That's a job for your frontend code to decide and format. When you used `toFixed()` what didn't work about it? What did you get back that you didn't expect? Please [edit] your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the code you have so far and describe the problem with it.

Comment: Hey, .toFixed(2) worked for me. It didn't work earlier because I was using the type number to return from my function and then assign it to my property which was a number type again however when I changed it to string, it worked. I think it's because toFixed() return a string representing a number in fixed point notation. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const fees: number = 10.20; 
console.log(fees.toFixed(2));

let s2: string = fees.toFixed(2);
console.log(s2);
```

Comment: .toFixed(2) worked for me. It didn't work earlier because I was using the type number to return from my function and then assign it to my property which was a number type again however when I changed it to string, it worked. I think it's because toFixed() return a string representing a number in fixed point notation.

Answer (score -1):

```
const fees: number = 10.20;
const formattedFees: string = fees.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });

console.log(formattedFees); // Output: "10.20"
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

Try ParseFloat() and it should work.

Comment: No, parseFloat() function is used to accept a string and convert it into a floating-point number.

Comment: This question is not about *parsing* a number, but *displaying* one. So this answer doesn't help.